# PHP: Initializing associative Array Fields and appending text to them - without knowing the key values beforehand

Tags: php, associative-array

I would like to improve resp. shorten my programming style for initializing fields of associative arrays and appending text to them.

The way I do it for years, example:

```
foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {
    if(!isset($mainArray[$tag])) {
        $mainArray[$tag] = '<li>'.$tag.'</li>';
    }
    else {
        $mainArray[$tag] .= '<li>'.$tag.'</li>';
    }
}
```

It just feels too long.

Can anyone provide me a shortcut for this? Can we directly init without checking with `isset`?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show an example of what `$mainArray` contains before entering the foreach loop?

Comment: `$mainArray` is empty before. `$mainArray = array();` And `$tagsArray` contains several tags (strings).

Comment: Can $tagsArray contain duplicate values, or are they unique?

Comment: `$tagsArray` does not contain unique values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP [Ternary Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary):

```
foreach( $tagsArray as $tag ) {
    $mainArray[$tag] = !isset( $mainArray[$tag] ) ? '<li>'.$tag.'</li>' : $mainArray[$tag] . '<li>'.$tag.'</li>' ;
}
```

If `$tagsArray` contains only unique values then there is no need to append:

```
foreach( $tagsArray as $tag ) 
    $mainArray[$tag] = '<li>'.$tag.'</li>';
```

Comment: That looks good to me, although there is still the isset check. I thought of the () ? : operators, however, did not get the idea to simply add the $mainArray[$tag] again after `:`

Comment: If there is no isset() check you will get Undefined index notice

Comment: Exactly, and I thought somebody knows a workaround resp. a shorthand notation that can do it without.

Comment: I doubt, since you try to append to an array member with a non-existent key

Comment: Error notices could be suppressed with @ sign, or by setting the error_reporting() to `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);`, but it is better not to have errors than to suppress them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could move the html part out of the if loop:

```
foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {
    if(!isset($mainArray[$tag])) {
        $mainArray[$tag] = '';
    }
    $mainArray[$tag] .= '<li>'.$tag.'</li>';
}
```

Then you could shorten it by using 1 line of code for the if:

```
foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {
    if(!isset($mainArray[$tag])) $mainArray[$tag] = '';
    $mainArray[$tag] .= '<li>'.$tag.'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: At time of posting OP specified that `$tagArray` contained unique values, after posting this answer I learned that there could be duplicates. I leave this answer here in case it can be useful, or be used as a starting point.

Since `$mainArray` is empty, and if `$tagsArray` contains unique values:

```
$tagsArray = array("first","second","third");

$tagsTextArray = array_map(function($tag) { 
                             return "<li>".$tag."</li>"; 
                           },
                           $tagsArray);

$mainArray = array_combine($tagsArray, $tagsTextArray);

var_dump($mainArray);
```

returns

```
array(3) {
  ["first"]=>
  string(14) "<li>first</li>"
  ["second"]=>
  string(15) "<li>second</li>"
  ["third"]=>
  string(14) "<li>third</li>"
}
```

If you want you could make that into a one-liner, but you'd lose legibility.

Comment: I am very sorry, it does not contain unique values. My fault. Comment above changed. However, you could leave your answer for others having the same issue but unique values.

Comment: OK, I've edited my answer to specify that it works for a unique tag array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ternary operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). For example :

```
foreach($tagsArray as $tag) {
    $mainArray[$tag] = isset($mainArray[$tag]) 
                     ? $mainArray[$tag] . '<li>' . $tag . '</li>' // if(isset($mainArray[$tag])), prepend it.
                     : '<li>' . $tag . '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Oh damn.. Has been answered by @Danijel. Weak connection.